# Flash only allows one class?

Tags: flash, class, data-structures

I wanted to create a customer class in flash to help store information on people more effectively.

```
class Teacher
{
    var id:uint;
    var username:String;
    var pword:String;
}
class Student
{
    var id:uint;
    var firstname:String;
    var surname:String;
    var pword:String;
    var teacher:String;
    var group:String;
    var tasksSet:Array;
}
public class Main extends MovieClip
```

{
....
}
But for some reason, flash will only allow one class. All the help on the internet goes WAY beyond this simple issue and I am new at flash and I have never had issues with making data structs before...

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are getting?

Comment: If I remember correctly you can only have one class per `.as` file, like in Java... I think...

Comment: The error is:5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: teacherInfo, Student

Comment: Then make a class that encapsulates all the other data objects that you need.

Comment: What does that mean?  Do i have to create a base class for the rest to inherit from?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can define any number of classes inside an Actionscript file. However, these "inner" classes are not accessible to anything but the main class that is being defined in the Actionscript file (ie: the class who's name is the same name as the .as file).

To avoid the error you were getting, the inner classes need to be defined outside of the package. For example, given the file `MyClass.as`:

```
package com.mydomain.whatever
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public function MyClass()
        {
            var e:ExampleInnerClass = new ExampleInnerClass();
             // do something
        }
    }
}

class ExampleInnerClass
{
    public function ExampleInnerClass()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```